# Why does 2e3 return 2000? Isn't 2 to the 3rd power equal to 8?

Tags: php, math, formula

This code:

```
$g = 2e3;
echo $g;
echo <br>;
echo "var_dump g gives:<br>";
```

Displays:

```
2000
float(2000)
```

I don't understand why it wouldn't display "8" and "float(8)"? Isn't 2 to the 3rd power equal to 8 ??

I tried looking for this question on this website already. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I did figure out that for 2e2 it displays 200. So it sounds like it just adds that many zeros to the end of the number instead of finding the 3rd power of 2. When I search for how to write exponential in php, the answers I've found said to use 'e' or 'E', but that doesn't seem to work or I've forgotten basic math. I'm sure somebody on here has a very simple answer for me.

Ok so why does `$g = 2^3;` give me 1?  How can I write 2 to the 3rd power in php?

Comment: `2^3` is 2 to the 3rd power, which is `8`

Comment: Thanks !  So how would I write 2^3? Cause when i try 2^3 it gives me 1.

Comment: @MarkBaker: Isn't `^` the XOR operator?

Comment: @RocketHazmat - PHP Fun #101 - `^` is the xor operator in PHP, but the power operator in mathematics

Comment: @newbie - you'd write it `2 ** 3` in PHP 5.6.0 or greater, or use `pow(2, 3)` in any version of PHP

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) (or in this case "E notation").

`2e3` is the same as `2 x 10^3`, which is `2000`.

If you want `2^3`, you can use

```
$g = pow(2, 3);
```

Or in PHP 5.6+:

```
$g = 2**3;
```

Note: You need to use `pow()` (or `**`) because in PHP, when you do `$g = 2^3;`, you are doing `2 XOR 3`.

Answer (score 0):

When you read something like `xey` that is called scientific notation. It represents `x times 10 to the power of y`, or essentilly, `add y zeroes to x` (for positive values of y). So in this case, it's `2 * 10^3 = 2,000`

Answer (score 0):

2e3 is scientific notation for 2000.0. It is the same as 2.0e03. Use the pow() function:

echo pow(2, 3); // 8